# Moving inner element when parent width is decreasing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hard to explain in the subject but basically I have two divs and to avoid any overlapping when I click the button I don't move the elements but instead changing the width of their parent containers.

What's surprising is that the one to the right edge of the screen is behaving nicely, giving us an impression that the inside element goes out of the screen.

On the left side it doesn't work the same. Even if, just for a test, changed the inner element to absolute positioning.

In other words when I click Run I expect the text on the left side to be pushed out of the screen after short time since the width of the parent is decreasing.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```js
$("#run").on("click", function() {
  $("#cont-left, #cont-right").toggleClass("hide");
});
```

```css
#cont-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#test {
  background: yellow;
  left: 0px;
}

#cont-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid green;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#test2 {
  background: pink;
  right: 0px;
}

#run {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#run:hover {
  background: green;
}

#cont-right.hide,
#cont-left.hide {
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont-right" class="hide">
  <div id="test">
    111<br />222<br />333
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cont-left" class="hide">
  <div id="test2">
    111<br/>222<br />333
  </div>
</div>
<span id="run">Run</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If it's just text, try `text-align`

If you're only working with text, the only change you need to make to your css to fix this is:

```
#cont-left {
  text-align: right;
}
```

## What if it's not: then it's time to `flex`

If you want to use more than text you should be using `display: flex;` so that you can `justify-content: flex-end;` (justify the content to the end). You will need to apply these to the containers `#cont-left` and `#cont-right`. For `#cont-right` use `justify-content: flex-start;`

However, when you apply those values, the divs `#test` and `#test2` will no longer take up their parent's width, therefore, you will be required to move the `background-color` to the parent divs or set `width: 100%;`

Below I have modified the code snippet to include the `flex` changes.

```js
$("#run").on("click", function() {
  $("#cont-left, #cont-right").toggleClass("hide");
});
```

```css
#cont-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background: yellow;
}

#cont-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: pink;
}

#run {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#run:hover {
  background: green;
}

#cont-right.hide,
#cont-left.hide {
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont-right" class="hide">
  <div id="test">
    111<br />222<br />333
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cont-left" class="hide">
  <div id="test2">
    111<br/>222<br />333
  </div>
</div>
<span id="run">Run</span>
```

Comment: I've started using flex but still amazed how useful it can be. I actually need the text to stay on the left..

Comment: I basically fell in love with flex :D